# Type ZoomPlugin[] has no common properties with type Plugin[] React

Tags: reactjs

I'm using `react-pdf-viewer` version `2.11.0`

When using the zoom plugin like below,

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Viewer } from '@react-pdf-viewer/core'
import { zoomPlugin } from '@react-pdf-viewer/zoom'

import '@react-pdf-viewer/core/lib/styles/index.css'
import '@react-pdf-viewer/zoom/lib/styles/index.css'
import { FixedSizeGrid } from 'react-window'

interface PDFViewerProps {
    fileUrl: string
}

const PDFViewer: React.FC<PDFViewerProps> = ({ fileUrl }) => {
    const zoomPluginInstance = zoomPlugin()
    const { ZoomInButton, ZoomOutButton, ZoomPopover } = zoomPluginInstance'
...

 <Viewer fileUrl={fileUrl} plugins={[zoomPluginInstance]} />
```

I get the following error

```
  Type 'ZoomPlugin[]' is not assignable to type 'Plugin[]'.
  Type 'ZoomPlugin' has no properties in common with type 'Plugin'.
    45 |                 }}
    46 |             >
  > 47 |                 <Viewer fileUrl={fileUrl} plugins={[zoomPluginInstance]} />
       |                                           ^
    48 |             </div>
    49 |         </div>
    50 |     )
```

The zoom plugin interface extends the plugin interface which is why I'm confused. Any ideas?

Comment: Found the solution. I just added a property in the Plugin interface into the ZoomPlugin interface and it compiled with no errors

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I just added a property in the Plugin interface into the ZoomPlugin interface and it compiled with no errors